# Identify outliers in chi-squared goodness of fit test

Tags: chi-squared-test, residuals, outliers

I am performing a chi-square goodness of fit test to compare an observed value with an expected value. The expected value is calculated from theory. p-value suggests statistical significance. How do I find out which cells contribute the most to the chi-square and what would be the best way to illustrate this graphically. I calculated the standardized residuals (observed-expected)/sqrt(expected). How do choose outliers in the plot? The real data is below.

| Motif | Observed | Predicted |
| --- | --- | --- |
| QGP | 1365 | 1100 |
| KGP | 1295 | 1280 |
| TGP | 1179 | 1141 |
| KGD | 774 | 611 |
| PGP | 746 | 649 |
| QGE | 616 | 388 |
| TGA | 605 | 298 |
| TGD | 584 | 545 |
| KGL | 518 | 257 |
| PGD | 500 | 310 |
| RGP | 451 | 333 |
| PGE | 394 | 229 |
| SGS | 366 | 95 |
| KGI | 365 | 192 |
| DGA | 362 | 93 |
| QGI | 325 | 165 |
| KGE | 290 | 452 |
| TGS | 264 | 246 |
| AGP | 260 | 260 |
| QGD | 246 | 525 |
| DGT | 236 | 59 |
| SGD | 232 | 211 |
| IGE | 212 | 73 |
| QGL | 207 | 221 |
| TGL | 181 | 229 |
| SGP | 180 | 442 |
| SGT | 171 | 74 |
| KGS | 169 | 276 |
| IGP | 166 | 206 |

Comment: An outlier has a really big standardized residual. Note that if one cell is way out of line  others may be too as a side-effect. I don't worry about what is "really big".

Comment: The contribution to $\chi^2$ is, by definition, the squared standardized residual.  Therefore, to determine which ones "contribute most," simply sort the standardized residuals by their magnitude and examine the largest.

Comment: Thank you of for the comments. @NickCox: I couldn't understand what you meant by "side-effect". I do have a cell that show "really big" standardised residuals. Is "Adjusted" Standardized Residuals a better way of comparing cells? Would it be possible to calculate it if the data has one column and multiple rows?

Comment: @NickCox: The sum of observed is not equal to the sum of predicted. I have seen research publications where chi-square goodness of fit has been calculated for "unequal" datasets. Is this an incorrect approach? What can be done to fix it?

Comment: Yes; it is incorrect from a chi-square viewpoint. If your theory is systematically wrong, that is what it is, and you can still calculate residuals.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that the chi-square test is not giving you the information you want.

A simple way to compare `observed` and `expected` is to plot the two variables and superimpose a 1:1 line.  This gives you some sense if there is a systematic difference in the results, and lets you visually identify those observation that are far from this 1:1 line.

In addition, a Bland-Altman plot may be more useful for this purpose. [Image, Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bland%E2%80%93Altman_plot#/media/File:Bland-Altman_Plot.svg)

From the data you posted, the observed values are somewhat systematically larger than the predicted values.  This is shown by the number of data points above and to the left of the 1:1 line.

Some R code follows.

[image: Scatter plot 1:1]

[image: Box plot]

```
Data=read.table(header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=TRUE, text="
motif    observed    predicted
QGP       1365       1100 
KGP       1295       1280 
TGP       1179       1141 
KGD        774        611 
PGP        746        649 
QGE        616        388 
TGA        605        298 
TGD        584        545 
KGL        518        257 
PGD        500        310 
RGP        451        333 
PGE        394        229 
SGS        366         95 
KGI        365        192 
DGA        362         93 
QGI        325        165 
KGE        290        452 
TGS        264        246 
AGP        260        260 
QGD        246        525 
DGT        236         59 
SGD        232        211 
IGE        212         73 
QGL        207        221 
TGL        181        229 
SGP        180        442 
SGT        171         74 
KGS        169        276 
IGP        166        206
")

plot(observed ~ predicted, data=Data)
abline(0,1, col="blue")

wilcox.test(Data$observed, Data$predicted, paired=TRUE)

Group = factor(
          c(rep("Predicted", length(Data$predicted)),
          rep("Observed", length(Data$observed))))

Response = c(Data$predicted, Data$observed)

plot(Response ~ Group)

library(FSA)

Summarize(Response ~ Group)

library(rcompanion)

efronRSquared(actual= Data$observed, predicted=Data$predicted, statistic="RMSE")
```

***EDIT: Some additional code to examine differences:***

```
Data$Diff = (Data$observed - Data$predicted)

hist(Data$Diff)

head(Data[order(Data$Diff),], n=10L)

head(Data[order(-Data$Diff),], n=10L)
```

***EDIT 2: Some additional code to examine z-scores of differences***

```
library(rcompanion)

Data$ZScore = blom(Data$Diff, method="zscore")

head(Data[order(Data$ZScore),], n=10L)

head(Data[order(-Data$ZScore),], n=10L)
```

***Edit 3: Chi-square goodness-fit-test and standardized residuals***

```
Data$prop = Data$predicted/sum(Data$predicted)

chisq.test(Data$observed, p=Data$prop)

Data$stdres = chisq.test(Data$observed, p=Data$prop)$stdres

head(Data[order(Data$stdres),], n=10L)

head(Data[order(-Data$stdres),], n=10L)

plot(Diff ~ stdres, data = Data)

summary(Data)
```

Comment: Thanks for the wonderful insight. I think the Bland-Altman plot is visually very appealing and also conveys the most information. I will definitely stick with it. However, generally speaking why should the sums of observed and calculated values be equal for a valid chi-square goodness of fit analysis. In my case, I am looking at the distribution of 20 natural amino acids on either side of another amino acid "G" in a human protein. There are 400 possible combinations but all combinations are not observed in Nature.

Comment: @Jalan , It's not clear to me how you are using a chi-square g-o-f test.  Instead, I'm operating under the assumption that what you really want to is determine a) if the observed values are systematically larger or smaller than the predicted values, b) which `motif`s would be responsible for large differences between observed and predicted, and c) if there is a pattern to these differences relative to the predicted values.

Comment: Perhaps you are not showing us combinations with zero observed but positive expected frequencies. You can’t ignore any such in a chi-square test.

Comment: @SalMangiafico: You are absolutely right on the purpose of the analysis. Its just that chi-square test has previously been used in multiple publications involving motifs such as these. Hence, for continuity sake I would like to stick to it. Otherwise, I have to justify to the reviewers why I chose to ignore established methods, which opens a pandora's box.

Comment: @NickCox: You are right! I was ignoring the "zero observed but positive expected" frequencies in calculating the sum of chi-squares. The sums of observed and expected are now equal. I guess then the chi-square analysis is valid in this case. This brings me to my final question. Is it possible to calculate "adjusted" standardised residuals for such a dataset?

Comment: Sure,  I doubt that the chi-square test will be especially helpful in practice but in principle (observed-expected)/sqrt(expected) and its more complicated relatives are things to look at here.

Comment: It may be fine to use chi-square g-o-f test.  ...  We expect the observed counts to have the same sum as the predicted counts.  As an example, imagine if I said we expect three times as many cats as dogs at the veterinarian's office.   If you count 100 animals there, and you get 60 cats and 40 dogs, when I tell you the expected counts, you would expect me to say 75 cats and 25 dogs.  Or I could have said 75% and 25% (or 0.75 and 0.25 as proportions). ...  I think some of the advice in comments on your post about using standardized residuals to suss out the largest "differences" makes sense.

Comment: P.S. I added some additional R code to my post to conduct the chi-square goodness-of-fit test and look at the standardized residuals. ...  It sounds like you will have somewhat different results when you include your observations with 0 counts.  ...  Practically, I imagine that you will probably want to look at those observations with the greatest numerical difference or greatest standardized residuals.

Comment: @SalMangiafico: Thank you so very much for the detailed post and scripts. The results are no dramatically different when using the whole dataset. The outliers with significantly higher standardised residual are independent of whether or not the observations with 0 counts are included.